# How to Move Object On a Particular Line in High Chart?

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

i'm using SVGRender element to clip circle on a line. Now i want to know what are the options available in highcharts to animate the circle in a particular line.
Thanks in Advance!!

```
var renderer;

renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
    $('#container')[0],
    400,
    300
);

var clipline=renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 100, 200, 50, 300, 100])
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();
  var circle = renderer.circle(25, 25, 10)
    .attr({ fill: 'red' })
    .add();


// Leave only the lower right quarter visible
circle.clip(clipline);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Clipping doesn't work in your example - `clip` function expects `clipRect` object as an argument: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/global#ClipRect In your code it's `SVGElement` object instead (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement). Please fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.I have another query, is it possible to animate marker to new location just like one in google maps?

Comment: Yes, you can use `animate` function on the point's `graphic` property: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#animate

Comment: i tried to animate  marker through an arc but i'm unsuccessful,please take a look at this code which i have tried [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b1g66ht6/15/)

Comment: I suppose that a good approach in this case is to utilize SVG's `animateMoton` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion Markers in Highcharts are SVG elements so it can be used on them. Additionally, Highcharts provides an interface for creating and managing SVG elements. First create path using `SVGRenderer.path` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path). Then create `animateMotion` tag using `defs` (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns) and append it to the marker's SVG tag.

Comment: thanks a lot.your answer is really useful